# Class "LaravelLocalization" not found

Tags: php, laravel

Class "LaravelLocalization" not found

I am using laraclassifie and I upload a plugin but i got this error

at extras/plugins/reviews/ReviewsServiceProvider.php:57

```
 53▕     public function setupRoutes(Router $router)

 54▕     {

 55▕         // Front

 56▕         $router->group([

 **57▕             'prefix'     => \LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),**

 58▕             'middleware' => ['web', 'localize', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeSessionRedirect'],

 59▕             'namespace' => 'extras\plugins\reviews\app\Http\Controllers'

 60▕         ], function ($router)

 61▕         {

  extras/plugins/reviews/ReviewsServiceProvider.php:33

  extras\plugins\reviews\ReviewsServiceProvider::setupRoutes()


  +7 vendor frames
▕  [internal]:0
  Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization), did you run `composer require mcamara/laravel-localization`?

and if you already run the installation command, you have to write the correct namespace of the class (please read [psr-4 specification](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)):

```php
<?php

$router->group([
    'prefix'     => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization::setLocale()
]);
```